# How to add keyword field in custom form programmatically?

Tags: tags, forms, html

For a lot of good reasons, I've inserted in my wordpress website a custom form, coded manually inside a custom plugin.

There is a simple way to add to raw code of the form a field for adding keywords (like the one this site use for 'tags', 'boxing' every word after a space)?

Comment: this link can help you in formatting your input as tags..http://jsbin.com/hehurot/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Cool! Thank you! You know, I can't understand what this line is about -> if(txt) $("<span/>",{text:txt.toLowerCase(), insertBefore:this}); It's a strange sintax

Comment: it wraps the text inside <span></span> and inserts it before the input tag

Comment: never seen this type of syntax. If you convert the reply in a proper answer I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link can help you in transforming text into tag-style boxes :-http://jsbin.com/hehurot/5/edit?html,js,output

Then you can store them individually as per your use case